# Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'proj1' (eclipse CDT)

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have a question about how to import an project that contains an existing make file into eclipse.
From reading the eclipse documentation it seems that i should use a "Makefile Project" 
Is this correct?
If so then the import of the project files seems ok, but when I run build I get:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'proj1'.
Internal error building project proj1 configuration Default
java.lang.NullPointerException
Internal error building project proj1 configuration Default
java.lang.NullPointerException

ok. So I i assume that i am getting this because the build target points to nothing. So i got to Project-> Properties -> C/C++ Build and all the "builder settings" are grayed out. 
My next attempt was to go to Project -> Make Target -> Create. What i see here is:

Target name:

Make Target:

Use Builder settings:

I made several attempts at putting values into these fields and running make again, but I get the same error.

When using eclipse CDT in the past i have always created the project myself so eclipse handled the whole make thing for me. But I am at a loss of how i actually tell CDT what make file to use or why I am receiving the above error message.

So i gues my question is if i want to import a C project with an existing file how do i tell eclipse what make file to use? In the flow i chose these options seemed grayed out.

I tried looking this up on stack exchange, but have not found an exact match for my situation

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something went wrong with your import. You should have imported your code via *Existing Code as Makefile Project*. The build command can be defined in the project-properties dialog, under C/C++ Build, Behaviour tab, in case you have a specific situation.